# redshift regexp_substr all occurrences

Tags: sql, regex, amazon-redshift, regexp-substr

I am trying to return all results that match a specific regex in Redshift database.

**Sample query**

```
WITH aa AS
(SELECT DISTINCT
id,
record,
regexp_substr(record, '(#{2})([A-Z]{2,3})',1,1),
REGEXP_COUNT(record, '(#{2})([A-Z]{2,3})')
FROM table_a)

SELECT
*
FROM aa
```

The above query returns the first occurrence and the total count of the occurrences.

Is there a way to return all occurrences? Maybe an iteration using a variable that is limited by the count?

```
regexp_substr(record, '(#{2})([A-Z]{2,3})',1,n)
```

There is a solution for Oracle with the CONNECT BY LEVEL, but that option seems to be unavailable for Redshift.

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, you can use [`split_part()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/SPLIT_PART.html) instead:

```
split_part(record, '##', <n>)
```

Then you can attempt to generate numbers and get the results:

```
with n as (
      select row_number() over () as n
      from t
      limit 10
     )
select t.*, split_part(record, '##', n.n) 
from t join
     n
     on split_part(record, '##', n.n) <> ''
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a field that contains sentences like this : "I want to ##DG split ##AFI ##GFA  the sentence #AA". I am trying to isolate the ## substrings and return a field like this : "##DG ##AFI ##GFA #AA". Not really sure whether your proposed solution identifies the regexp and collects them in a field. It seems to me that it identifies the ## only and does not identify regexp